# 100% Packet loss when pinging my external IP

Tags: networking, ping

There's a ddns domain pointing to my external ip & I am able to ping it from an off site computer.  However, when I ping my external ip from my local computer, all of the packets fail & I end up with 100% packet loss.

Ping from offsite computer:

```
PING something.mydomain.com (xx.xxx.xx.xxx) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from xx.xxx.xx.xxx: icmp_seq=1 ttl=42 time=16.8 ms
64 bytes from xx.xxx.xx.xxx: icmp_seq=2 ttl=42 time=23.5 ms
64 bytes from xx.xxx.xx.xxx: icmp_seq=3 ttl=42 time=25.1 ms
64 bytes from xx.xxx.xx.xxx: icmp_seq=4 ttl=42 time=16.6 ms
64 bytes from xx.xxx.xx.xxx: icmp_seq=5 ttl=42 time=18.9 ms
64 bytes from xx.xxx.xx.xxx: icmp_seq=6 ttl=42 time=17.2 ms
64 bytes from xx.xxx.xx.xxx: icmp_seq=7 ttl=42 time=18.9 ms
64 bytes from xx.xxx.xx.xxx: icmp_seq=8 ttl=42 time=17.3 ms

--- something.mydomain.com ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 received, 0% packet loss, time 1404ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 16.636/19.326/25.111/3.024 ms
Remote PING completed.
```

Ping from local computer:

```
PING something.mydomain.com (xx.xxx.xx.xxx) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- something.mydomain.com ping statistics ---
77 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 77813ms
```

(PII has been obscured)

I'm kinda new to ubuntu & am not sure what other information would be helpful in this case so please ask!

Comment: tracert something.mydomain.com for inside network?

Comment: This is probably not a problem with Ubuntu, but rather that your router does not support NAT hairpin, e.g. packets coming from inside destined for the outside interface.

Comment: @vidarlo You are indeed correct.... *sigh* routers are such a pain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So biased on @vidarlo's comment I looked into NAT hairpinning or NAT loopback which is what allows computers in your network to access the external interface.  Some routers firmware simply does not have this functionality.  In some cases you can flash 3rd party firmware though.

However, in my case, I use the Xfinity supplied router, which I have confirmed neither has this nor has a way to enable it as per [this thread](http://forums.xfinity.com/t5/Your-Home-Network/From-within-my-home-network-external-router-IP-does-not-work/td-p/1474663):

> If this is a Comcast supplied gateway device, you will not be able to change it, nor will you be a ble to load anything but the Comcast firmware...

Which sucks...   Time to go router shopping!